# Want to Create one PL/SQL Block in which insert and update will happen

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

i have two table "supplier" and "product_stock". I want to create a pl/sql block, when ever an insert takes place in the "supplier" table that need to be updated in the "product_stock" table if the same product is available. It needs to update the "Quantity" column value [Old value + New value]. If the product is not available then it will be inserted.
Kindly suggest me how to achieve this. I tried it with functions and select into method, but it wont worked out for me.

Comment: Post the function you tried.  Show the sample data from all the tables involved and also the end result you want. Have you also considered using  triggers?

Comment: mysql and oracle / plsql are different. don't include irrelevant tags.

Comment: Hint is you need to create a trigger on `supplier` table. Google out how to create trigger and i hope you would be able to do it.